# Onsen-UI - Place sliding-menu on right

Tags: onsen-ui

Is it possible to place the sliding-menu on the right side?

All the examples and the sample apps that I have tested have the sliding-menu on the left.

Comment: This question is very vague, and it is not obvious what you are asking. Please improve your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
<sliding-menu side="right">
```

**Explanation**
It is officially supported by Onsen-UI as of version 1.2.2. Not sure if it was supported before this version. I myself have just started using it a few days ago. Here is a codepen of sliding menu with the attribute side="left" [codepen.io/onsen/pen/IDvFJ](http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/IDvFJ) Change it to right and see the results

Comment: It is officially supported by Onsen-UI as of version 1.2.2. Not sure if it was supported before this version. I myself have just started using it a few days ago. Here is a codepen of sliding menu with the attribute side="left" http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/IDvFJ
Change it to right and see the results.

Answer (score 2):

right side sliding-menu is not supported yet. Please open an issue here https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues?direction=desc&page=1&sort=updated&state=open